# Integrating facebook with my actionscript application

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

I would like to integrate facebook in my actionscript application. I am using facebook actionscript api available from code.google.com.

I would like to know if there is any way to creating custom login dialog rather than using the default facebook login dialog as i want the user to just sign in to facebook rather than exploring the other fields like "Sign up" and "Forgot password"

I cant use the current api as websites use it for logging to facebook. It is open to sign ups exploring other languages.

I would like to prevent the whole thing by customizing the login dialog. Does facebook provide something for that? Or can it be done it in any way?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I doubt it's possible to customize the dialog.  I've never seen an example of it in the wild.

Comment: What do you mean about exploring other languages?  Do you mean having your app "localized"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, never seen a way to customize it to that level where you can remove core functionality of their dialogs.  The advanced auth dialog and the registration plugins can get customized more than the old one.